# How to troubleshoot Informatica Java Transformation compilation error?

Tags: java, informatica

I have an issue with my Informatica PowerCenter Designer Java Transformation. Version 10.1.0

I have all the required jar files added to the Classpath. But when I compile it says: JTXPartitionDriverImplGen.java:12M

When I click on Apply, it says: Compilation of Java code failed - transformation invalid.

When I validate the mapping it says: Byte code for the transformation is not in the repository. Java transformation is invalid.

We tried the same exact steps on my co-workers machine and it compiled successfully.

I'm running out of ideas on how to fix this. Google search hasn't helped. I've tried different versions of JDK and JRE. Finally I decided to re-install this version of Informatica Designer and it gave me the same error.

I do have another (older) version of PowerCenter Designer that I need for a different project. Could conflicting versions be causing this?

Please provide any ideas if you can. Thank you.

Comment: can you post the complete error message?

Comment: That is the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

**A few possible reasons for this are as follows:**
When different versions of PowerCenter clients are installed on the same windows machine.
When a different version of PowerCenter client is used other than the PowerCenter server.
The Windows machine has JDK/JRE, PATH, CLASSPATH or JAVA_HOME environment variables set with a Java path set.
In some cases, it is also observed that the issue is caused when setting the _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable at the Windows client machine.

To resolve this issue, ensure that JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME/JRE_HOME, PATH, and CLASSPATH environment variables are set to a correct path where Java is present.
Also, ensure that  _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable is not set on the server.
If so, update the environment variable accordingly to have the correct Java loaded and ensure that _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable is unset before starting the Informatica Clients.

**In case if above mentioned solution doesn't fix your problem, please edit the Java transformation to resolve this issue:**
Go to 'Java Code' tab
Click on the settings
Click on browse and add the following jar files from PowerCenter_client_installation\bin directory:

C:\Informatica\10.x.x\clients\PowerCenterClient\client\bin\pmjtx.jar
C:\Informatica\10.x.x\clients\PowerCenterClient\client\bin\pmserversdk.jar​
In addition, if the above doesn't work you might want to,
Create the environment variable JAVA_HOME
Start the Designer as Administrator